# Google Pay(Tez) Integration in android what is the status for the case 'Amount debited from account but receiver didn't received'?

Tags: android, google-tez

I have integrated Google Pay(tez) in my android app by following [this code](https://github.com/googletez/inapp-payment-samples/blob/master/java/app/src/main/java/com/google/tezdemo/inappsample/MainActivity.java) . Here on Activity result i have two cases normally which is 'SUCCESS' and 'FAILURE' when return Intent from Google Pay Page. But, I have made a transaction which have the case 'Amount debited from account but Receiver not get the amount we (Google pay) will update once this transaction is success or failure' for this case the google pay didn't make the return intent .

How to handle the third case ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, still waiting

Comment: The way i see it is that you need to use the Transaction Details API to query after some time if the transaction in question was successful or not. https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/otherapis/omnichannel/get-transaction-details

Comment: Yes, I saw the same but another problem is the return intent from google pay to my app is not working, It is returning only if success or failure

Comment: ohh, that`s a problem. what are you doing to tackle this problem? having some timer based system to consider this case as failure?

Comment: I think using timer based system is not a good format because google pay takes more time than usual for giving result.